# How to monitoring directory for files in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, file, directory, monitoring, delphi-xe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi notification when a file gets updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418562/delphi-notification-when-a-file-gets-updated)

Need monitoring for create files and count them.
OS: WinXP and high.

Answer (score 8):

Last year I had the same need and tried out Iztok Kacin's Directory Watch.  He responded to email and was very helpful in answering my questions.

His code worked, but I needed to be notified at the moment a file in a specific folder was *closed*, which for some odd reason, the ReadDirectoryChanges API (on which it depends) from Microsoft (maddeningly) doesn't provide. I also seem to recall that Iztok's code used threads and didn't feel light-weight enough for my needs.

I ended up using a surprisingly simple approach that has worked wonderfully for me. On a TTimer event that fires every few seconds, I use FindFirst on the folder I'm monitoring. All files found are put in a persistent TStringList.  Any file that is found that isn't already in the StringList from previous TTimer events is new.   (To detect if a file is closed, I try to open the file in exclusive mode. If I can't open it, then it's not added to the TStringList so it's checked on the next event.)

I was quite hesitant to use this approach, thinking it was far too brute-force. But, for the needs I had, this solution has worked out wonderfully and thankfully, involves a small amount of very simple code that is easy to understand and maintain.

HTH

Comment: Why did someone vote down my answer above?

Comment: Please note there is a small bug in that library. You need to add Terminate in TDirWatchThread.Execute (after SignalError(ErrorMessage)) - Without this it enters an infinite loop when you delete all files from folder then the folder itself  !

Answer (score 6):

You may want to take a look at [this article](http://www.osnews.com/story/7376/A_Directory_Monitor_Class_For_Delphi) (A Directory Monitor Class For Delphi), and also at this function from Windows API: [ReadDirectoryChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You should also take a look at this SO question since it may suit your needs: [Delphi notification when a file gets updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418562/delphi-notification-when-a-file-gets-updated)