# Wait for process started by IContextMenu.InvokeCommand

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a `TListView` whose items are files, which the user can open via double clicking on them.

To do this, I save the file in the windows temp folder, start a thread that opens the saved file with `ShellExecuteEx()`, and let it wait for `ShellExecuteInfo.hProcess`, like this:

```
TNotifyThread = class(TThread)
private
  FFileName: string;
  FFileAge: TDateTime;
public
  constructor Create(const FileName: string; OnClosed: TNotifyEvent); overload;
  procedure Execute; override;

  property FileName: String read FFileName;
  property FileAge: TDateTime read FFileAge;
end;

{...}

constructor TNotifyThread.Create(const FileName: string; OnClosed: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  if FileExists(FileName) then
    FileAge(FileName, FFileAge);

  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  OnTerminate := OnClosed;
  FFileName := FileName;

  Resume;
end;

procedure TNotifyThread.Execute;
var
  se: SHELLEXECUTEINFO;
  ok: boolean;
begin
  with se do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    fMask := SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;
    lpVerb := PChar('open');
    lpFile := PChar(FFileName);
    lpParameters := nil;
    lpDirectory := PChar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)));
    nShow := SW_SHOW;
  end;

  if ShellExecuteEx(@se) then
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(se.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if se.hProcess <> 0 then
      CloseHandle(se.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

This way, I can use the `TThread.OnTerminate` event to write back any changes made to the file after the user closes it.

I now show the windows context menu with the help of `JclShell.DisplayContextMenu()` (which uses `IContextMenu`).

**MY GOAL: To wait for the performed action (e.g. 'properties' , 'delete', ..) chosen in the context menu to finish (or get notified in any kind of fashion), so that I can check the temporary file for changes to write those back, or remove the `TListItem` in case of deletion.**

Since `CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO` does not return a process handle like `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` does, I am unable to do it in the same way.

Assigning `MakeIntResource(commandId-1)` to `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.lpVerb` made the call to `ShellExecuteEx()` crash with an `EAccessViolation`. This method seems unsupported for `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`.

I have tried to get the command string with `IContextMenu.GetCommandString()` and the command ID from `TrackPopupMenu()` to later pass it to `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.lpVerb`, but `GetCommandString()` wouldn't return commands for some items clicked.

**working menu items:**

> properties, edit, copy, cut, print, 7z: add to archive (verb is 'SevenZipCompress', wont return processHandle), KapserskyScan (verb is 'KL_scan', wont return processHandle)

**not working:**

> anything within "open with" or "send to"

Is this simply the fault of the `IContextMenu` implementation?

Maybe it has something to do with my use of `AnsiString`s? I couldn't get `GCS_VERBW` to work, though. Are there better ways to reliably get the `CommandString` than this?

```
function CustomDisplayContextMenuPidlWithoutExecute(const Handle: THandle; 
const Folder: IShellFolder;
  Item: PItemIdList; Pos: TPoint): String;
var
  ContextMenu: IContextMenu;
  ContextMenu2: IContextMenu2;
  Menu: HMENU;
  CallbackWindow: THandle;
  LResult: AnsiString;
  Cmd: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (Item = nil) or (Folder = nil) then
    Exit;
  Folder.GetUIObjectOf(Handle, 1, Item, IID_IContextMenu, nil,
    Pointer(ContextMenu));
  if ContextMenu <> nil then
  begin
    Menu := CreatePopupMenu;
    if Menu <> 0 then
    begin
      if Succeeded(ContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(Menu, 0, 1, $7FFF, CMF_EXPLORE)) then
      begin
        CallbackWindow := 0;
        if Succeeded(ContextMenu.QueryInterface(IContextMenu2, ContextMenu2)) then
        begin
          CallbackWindow := CreateMenuCallbackWnd(ContextMenu2);
        end;
        ClientToScreen(Handle, Pos);
        cmd := Cardinal(TrackPopupMenu(Menu, TPM_LEFTALIGN or TPM_LEFTBUTTON or
          TPM_RIGHTBUTTON or TPM_RETURNCMD, Pos.X, Pos.Y, 0, CallbackWindow, nil));
        if Cmd <> 0 then
        begin
          SetLength(LResult, MAX_PATH);
          cmd := ContextMenu.GetCommandString(Cmd-1, GCS_VERBA, nil, LPSTR(LResult), MAX_PATH);
          Result := String(LResult);
        end;
        if CallbackWindow <> 0 then
          DestroyWindow(CallbackWindow);
      end;
      DestroyMenu(Menu);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I have read Raymond Chen's blog on [How to host an IContextMenu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823/), as well as researched on MSDN (for example [`CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-_cminvokecommandinfo), [`GetCommandString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-getcommandstring), [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow) and [`TrackPopupMenu()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu)), but I might have missed something trivial.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not feasible because not all these activities will spawn a new process dedicated to a single task. In fact, your first step (using ShellExecuteEx and then waiting for the returned process to terminate) will not work in all cases. Many applications (like Winword, Notepad++, ...) do not spawn a new process to open a document if they are already running but will reuse the existing process.

Comment: FYI, the `CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO.fMask` field has a `CMIC_MASK_NOASYNC` flag available on Vista+: "*The implementation of `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand` should be synchronous, **not returning before it is complete**.*"

Comment: Another approach would be to monitor the files for changes, See this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418562/delphi-notification-when-a-file-gets-updated

Comment: @RemyLebeau that was one of the first things i tried :) usage of flag `CMIC_MASK_NOASYNC` seems to be merely a suggestion to the implementation, my application did not once wait for `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand` to finish. _"The implementation of IContextMenu::InvokeCommand should be synchronous, not returning before it is complete. Since this is recommended, **calling applications** that specify this flag **cannot guarantee that this request will be honored** if they are not familiar with the implementation of the verb that they are invoking."_

Comment: @Brian thanks for the link, monitoring the file(s) directly seems a more reliable and cleaner solution on first look, i will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [TJvChangeNotify](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvChangeNotify) to monitor the windows temp folder, while keeping the monitored-files in a `TDictionary<FileName:String, LastWrite: TDateTime>`.

So whenever TJvChangeNotify fires the [OnChangeNotify](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvChangeNotify.OnChangeNotify) event, i can check which of my monitored-files have been deleted (by checking existence) or have changed (by comparing the last write time).

Example `ChangeNotifyEvent`:

```
procedure TFileChangeMonitor.ChangeNotifyEvent(Sender: TObject; Dir: string;
  Actions: TJvChangeActions);
var
  LFile: TPair<String, TDateTime>;
  LSearchRec: TSearchRec;
  LFoundErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  for LFile in FMonitoredFiles do
  begin
    LFoundErrorCode := FindFirst(LFile.Key, faAnyFile, LSearchRec);
    try
      if LFoundErrorCode = NOERROR then
      begin
        if LSearchRec.TimeStamp > LFile.Value then
        begin
          // do something with the changed file
          {...}

          // update last write time
          FMonitoredFiles.AddOrSetValue(LFile.Key, LSearchRec.TimeStamp);
        end;
      end // 
      else if (LFoundErrorCode = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) then
      begin
        // do something with the deleted file
        {...}

        // stop monitoring the deleted file
        FMonitoredFiles.Remove(LFile.Key);
      end;
    finally
      System.SysUtils.FindClose(LSearchRec);
    end;
  end;
end;
```